# iTextSharp embedded MP4 into PDF, however, it can't play from Acrobat Reader

Tags: flash, pdf, video, itext

I've spent a few weeks on trying to insert video into a PDF and just can't get it to work as I expect it to. Following the book I use annotations and have tried many different file formats (mp4, wav, avi, etc). With mp4's and all formats except swf I get a PDF that when I click on the video to play in Adobe Reader X I get told there's no media player, I need a 3rd party plugin and get directed to Adobe.com where I get told there's no plugin. SWF's embed and play but the quality is low and the file size is huge. There's no player though with a start/pause, etc.

[image: get media player]
When I clicked "Get Media Player" button, it jump to url: "http://cgi.adobe.com/special/acrobat/mediaplayerfinder/mediaplayerfinder.cgi?" with content - "**Sorry, browsing is not allowed in this directory.**"

In Adobe Acrobat I can click Insert Video, select an MP4 and the video gets embedded with a nice video player and everything works perfectly and has a small file size. I tried creating my own buttons in iText, but had the same 3rd party plugin errors. Am I missing something? Shouldn't I bet able to embed mp4's directly into a PDF and have them just work? They are h.264 encoded so should work!

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, targetPath.getText(), "Video", null, true); 
var annot = PdfAnnotation.createScreen(writer,rectangle,"HIP Video", fs, "video/mp4", false); 
writer.addAnnotation(annot);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Adobe Flash player is deprecated. But here is your answer https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Play-video-from-pdf-error-q89380.aspx

The link now is http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/reader-acrobat-flash-player-download.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Fix your bots already, if you use them, the question was about the new link. LOLOL.

Comment: I am not a bot :) also, I was referring to the first link. "But here is your answer" If the link is dead then OP will not know what you tried to link....